# Struggling to convert CRC-16 0x8408 reversed from C to Java

Tags: java, c

I've received the task to convert a CRC routine from C to java but I'm really struggling to get the CRC to match up with the documented example.  Here's my documentation:

> The algorithm used is CCITT-16 (0x1021 or
>   0x8408 reversed).The remainder is
>   initialized to all 1's (0xFFFF)

```
WORD crc16_lsb(BYTE *pData, WORD length)
 {
     BYTE i;
     WORD data, crc;

     crc = 0xFFFF;
     if (length == 0)
         return 0;
     do
         {
             data = (WORD)0x00FF & *pData++;
             crc = crc ^ data;
             for (i = 8; i > 0; i--)
                 {
                     if (crc & 0x0001)
                         crc = (crc >> 1) ^ 0x8408;
                     else
                         crc >>= 1;
                 }
         }
     while (--length);
     crc = ~crc;
     return (crc);
 }
```

As an example, for a Receiver Status Request message made up of the following bytes: **1B FF 41 00**

The following 2 byte CRC would be calculated: **27 66**

I started with the following javacode from here http://www.cs.princeton.edu/introcs/51data/CRC16CCITT.java.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to mention what part exactly you need help with. Either post your current attempt so people can improve upon it, or be more specific.

Comment: Please do not remove questions when answers are already given. I've rolledback the deletion. If you actually made a mistake, then just post your own answer explaining the mistake and the actual problem/solution and then move on. Else if the posted answer has it after all right, the just mark it accepted and move on. That's how it works here.

Answer (score 1):

Without any closer look, you should know that Java has *TWO* shift-right operators: ">>" and ">>>".  They differ in how the most significant bit is treated, and it may very well be that ">>>" is the most appropriate for CRC-calculations.